# how configure timeouts, retries or max-attempts in differents queues with spring rabbitmq

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Is it possible to make these settings for each queue? I have queues that are important so i need a larger number of retries, but have less important queues that I do not want to configure retry, attempt, etc

```
public Queue newQueue(String name) {
    return new Queue(name, durable, exclusive, autoDelete, arguments);
}
```

I saw that in the Queue class, it is possible to pass an argument map as the last parameter, but I do not know if it would be here, or via properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I had to create a listener factory with a retry interceptor, in the retry interceptor I set the value for max attempts.

Maybe works for you:

```
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Autowired
private SomeService someService;

@RabbitListener(id = "queueListener", queues = "queueName",
        containerFactory = "listenerContainerFactory")
@RabbitHandler
public void notifyLegacyListener(SomeObject obj) {
    someService.doSomething(obj);
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory listenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
    factory.setAdviceChain(new Advice[] {retries()});
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public RetryOperationsInterceptor retries() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless().maxAttempts(Queues.QUEUE_LEGACY.getMaxAttempts())
            .backOffOptions(1000,
                    3.0, 10000)
            .recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer()).build();
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Such things are not properties of the queue, they are properties of a retry advice added to the listener container. Use a different container/advice for each queue. See the Spring AMQP reference manual.

Answer (score 2):

I was able change max retries and back-off strategy in configuration like this:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    listener:
      simple:
        retry:
          enabled: true
          initial-interval: 1000
          max-attempts: 3
          max-interval: 10000
          multiplier: 2.0
```

Messages that are still failing will be discarded with a warning with this config. See [this article for configuring dead letter queue](http://lifeinide.com/post/2017-12-29-spring-boot-rabbitmq-transactions/)