# How to restart kubernetes pod when issue because of Rabbit MQ connectivity in logs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring Boot 2 standalone application( not REST service) which connect to rabbit MQ and process message. The application is deployed in kubernetes. While it work great, but when Rabbit MQ remain down for little longer and in logs I see hearbeat exception 60sec and eventually connection get drop even if the rabbit mq comes up after certain time:
[Automatic retry connection to broker by spring-rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981299/automatic-retry-connection-to-broker-by-spring-rabbitmq)
https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html

While I try to manage above issue by increasing number of retry :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385119/how-configure-timeouts-retries-or-max-attempts-in-differents-queues-with-spring

but after expiry of retry still above issue comes.
How can I reboot/delete-recreate pod if I see above issue in logs from kubernetes.

Comment: Isn't the real problem here that rabbit MQ is periodically down? Do you know, why it behaves like that?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `actuator`, which has a `/actuator/health` endpoint. (Note that the recent version also add `/actuator/health/liveness` and `/actuator/health/readiness`).

You can assign the endpoint to `livenessProbe` property of k8s. Then it will automatically restart when it is necessary. You can parameterize, when your app is down if necessary.

See the docs:

[Kubernetes liveness probe](http://%20https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)

[Spring actuator health](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/liveness-and-readiness-probes-with-spring-boot)

Comment: But mine is not a REST service

Comment: actuator creates the endpoints, you dont need to create any rest service, nor add any dependencies but actuator. or you do not want to run on embadded server, just as plain jar?